# Passing navigation props from parent to child component

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I am developing an application which starts from `App.js`. If user is using app, first time then `LoginScreen` rendered and if user is logged in already then `HomeScreen` rendered.

Here's my `App.js`,

```
export default class App extends Component{

    state = {
        isFirstTime: true,
    }

    renderIf(condition, content) {
        if (condition) {
            return content;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    render(){
        const { navigate } = this.props;
        return(
            <View style = {{flex: 1}} >
                {
                    this.renderIf(this.state.isFirstTime, <LoginScreen />)
                }
                {
                    this.renderIf(!this.state.isFirstTime, <HomeScreen />)
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

But now when I am trying to navigate from `LoginScreen` to `HomeScreen` using `StackNavigator`, I am getting an error that is,

```
Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
```

So, simply mine question is that how to pass props from parent component to child component. That is I want to pass, `this.props.navigation` from `App.js` to `LoginScreen.js`

Answer (score 4):

when you render your component just pass it like this `<LoginScreen navigate={this.props.navigate} />`

on your Component LoginScreen you can get it by using `const navigate = this.props.navigate;`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your navigation props from a container screen to children components by doing this:

`<LoginScreen navigation={this.props.navigation} />`

Then in your child component, receive it and use it in an action like this:

`this.props.navigation.navigate('placeToGo');`

Comment: can i use it to call parent class from child component?